# VK API, отправка сообщения в ЛС

Tags: vkontakte-api

Можно ли использовать VK API для отправки личных сообщений подписчикам?
Ну допустим, юзер авторизовался у меня на сайте через VK, далее, ему на почту отправляется сообщение об успешной регистрации.

А можно ли это сообщение отправить ему в ЛС самого Вконтакте? Если так просто при регистрации нельзя, то есть ли какой-либо способ по другому это сделать? (ну может есть возможность, создать какое-либо приложение в ВК, юзер руками подтверждает в нем доступ, после сайт либо напрямую через API либо через это приложение шлет юзеру уведомляшки в ВК). Ну это всё мысли. Реально ли это вообще, каким-либо образом слать юзеру с сервера сайта (прямо или косвенно) уведомления в ЛС Вконтакте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли использовать VK API для отправки личных сообщений подписчикам? Ну допустим, юзер авторизовался у меня на сайте через VK, далее, ему на почту отправляется сообщение об успешной регистрации.

Можно

> А можно ли это сообщение отправить ему в ЛС самого Вконтакте?

Можно

> создать какое-либо приложение в ВК, юзер руками подтверждает в нем доступ, после сайт либо напрямую через API либо через это приложение шлет юзеру уведомляшки в ВК)

Не обязательно чтобы пользователь разрешал доступ. Вы же ему будете слать сообщение не из его же аккаунта?

> Реально ли это вообще, каким-либо образом слать юзеру с сервера сайта
>   (прямо или косвенно) уведомления в ЛС Вконтакте?

Реально. [Вот](http://vk.com/dev/messages.send) нужный вам метод.

Answer (score 2):

Напрямую нельзя. Документация ВК о **messages.send**:

> Данный метод доступен только Standalone-приложениям.

Поэтому необходимо чтобы пользователь перешел по ссылке типа `http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=<app_id>&scope=messages,offline&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=popup&response_type=token` (где *app_id* - идентификатор предварительно зарегистрированного приложения *Standalone*) и самостоятельно передал *access_token* в ваше приложение. С полученным токеном можно вызывать метод **messages.send**. См. https://toster.ru/q/223460

Comment: если приведённая вами ссылка станет недействительной, ваш ответ потеряет смысл. лучше привести здесь основную информацию, а ссылку дать в качестве дополнительной иллюстрации.